# Can i generate a class automatically on method call?

Tags: asp.net

I have created an extended method for DataTable. I want to generate a class automatically in my solution when i call that method while writing a code as Visual studio does when it doesnt find the method.
e.g mytable.mymethod(); Generate a class

Is there any way i can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to dynamically create a class:

[Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx) and [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx).

Second one is not recommended because it will create a new assembly and load it which can cause Memory-Leak-like problems.

You can also achieve some of the features using [dymanic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject%28VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to write a [Visual Studio plugin](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/WriteExtensions.aspx), detect when you've used a method that doesn't exist and generated it. Or use an existing plugin like [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_generation.html) which will make it easier to generate the method you're calling.